# How to enable css cursor:pointer (the hand symbol) in mobile/tablet browser (touch screen)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, accessibility

```
.HandSign{    
    cursor: pointer;
 }
```

Above CSS style works absolutely fine in desktop browser. I would like to know if there is any way to show the hand symbol as soon as we touch the related control in mobile/tablet browser.

Comment: Isn't the idea behind touch not to have a mouse pointer? I think you need to create some custom pointer if you need that for touch devices

Comment: It would be hidden by your finger.  What is the purpose of this requirement?  If you want the touch to be more visible then there are much better ways to highlight the touched element.

Comment: The question is too unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about just in CSS but in JS/jQuery it could be done by creating an element:

```
<span id='customPointer'><img source='pointer.png'></span>
```

CSS:

```
#customPointer{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display: hidden;
}
```

Then use JS/jQuery to move/show the element with each click. Click is fired for both desktop and mobile.:

```
$('body').onClick(function(event){
        setPointer(event);
    });

function setPointer(e){
    if(e.touches){
        $('#customPointer').css({'top': e.pageY, 'left': e.pageX, 'display': 'inline-block'});
    }
}
```

A few notes on this:

1. Touchscreen desktops might behave oddly
2. The if(e.touches) will determine if it was actually from a mouse or a touchscreen to prevent it from doing anything with true mouse events
3. You might also want to add something for onmousemove to change display back to hidden if a mouse is moved.